# When submiting a contact us form I wanted to stay in this cantact form

Tags: php, html, css

I am new in HTML and PHP, I have created a contact form for the users where they can add their messages.  When they click on the send button I want the page to stay on this contact form and show a text message below that says it is succesfully sent. Here is my code some of it .

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
        echo "please enter the name";
        }else {
            if (!isset($_POST["emailaddress"])) {
            echo "please enter the email adresse ";
            }else {
                if (!isset($_POST["subject"])) {
                echo " Please enter the message ";
            } else {
                $nom = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['emailaddress'];
                $msg = $_POST['subject'];

                $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (name, email, message) VALUES ('$nom', '$email', '$msg') ";

                if (!mysql_query($sql)){
                    die ('error : ' . mysql_error());
                } else {
                    mysql_close($link);
                    ?>
                        </br></br>
                            <p25><center>sent succesfully! thanks</center></p25>s
                        <?php
                        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'no-sidebar.php'\",8000);</script>";
```

Comment: The person who downvoted this, you should encourage the new developer to learn things instead of downvoting without any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand each line of code.

```
if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "please enter the name";
 }
```

The page will get reloaded on the first instance.

You need to do the form validation part in `javascript`. In this way, if some validation error happens, it can be displayed somewhere in the page without reloading it.

Then send the data to php through `ajax`, where you set your model and pass it to database and send a response back to javascript which can then print the message that the form has been submitted successfully.

Here's what I'm saying:

```
<input type="text" id="email" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Javascript Part:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#submit').on('click', function(){
             var email = $('#email').val();
             if(email.trim().length === 0){

                 $('#status').html('Email not provided');
            }else{

              $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : {action: 'sendData' , email : email}, // object
                url : 'example.php',
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){

                    $('#status').html(response);
                }

              });
            }
       });
   });
```

And in the php side, then you can just get the value which is already validated and return true or false based on your data insertion result to database.

```
example.php

   <?php
      if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'sendData'){
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         if(dbinsertion successful){
             echo "Success";
         }else{
             echo "Something went wrong";
         } 
      }
   ?>
```

You have to use `jquery` here. Hope you understood.

Comment: yes, thanks i have to study Javascript and jquery now to do this, i thought that it was eassy. thanks for the help .